# awk script to calculate delay from trace file ns-3

Tags: awk, ascii, ns-3

I want to measure time between transmitted and received packets in below trace file.

Input:

```
 + 0.01 /NodeList/1/DeviceList/1/$ns3::PointToPointNetDevice/TxQueue/Enqueue
 - 0.01 /NodeList/1/DeviceList/1/$ns3::PointToPointNetDevice/TxQueue/Dequeue
 r 0.0200001 /NodeList/0/DeviceList/2/$ns3::PointToPointNetDevice/MacRx
 + 0.11 /NodeList/1/DeviceList/1/$ns3::PointToPointNetDevice/TxQueue/Enqueue
 - 0.11 /NodeList/1/DeviceList/1/$ns3::PointToPointNetDevice/TxQueue/Dequeue
 r 0.12 /NodeList/0/DeviceList/2/$ns3::PointToPointNetDevice/MacRx
 + 0.12 /NodeList/0/DeviceList/3/$ns3::PointToPointNetDevice/TxQueue/Enqueue
 - 0.12 /NodeList/0/DeviceList/3/$ns3::PointToPointNetDevice/TxQueue/Dequeue
 r 0.120001 /NodeList/2/DeviceList/2/$ns3::PointToPointNetDevice/MacRx
```

Here + represents transmitted data and r represents received data. 2nd column in the trace file shows the time.

How can I measure time between r and + for the whole file using awk code?

The expected output can be as below:

Output:

```
  0.0100001
  0.01
  0.000001
```

I'll be grateful if anyone helps.

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output. If you need an external site to show it then you haven't put the effort into making it Minimal (as in [mcve]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generated my own trace file, called `trace`, as follows:

```
+ 0.1 Stuff stuff and more stuff
- 0.2 Yet more stuff
r 0.4 Something new
+ 0.8 Something else, not so new
- 1.6 Jiggery
r 3.2 Pokery
+ 6.4 Higgledy Piggledy
```

Then, I would approach your question with `awk` as follows:

```
awk '/^+/{tx=$2}  /^r/{rx=$2; d=rx-tx; $1=$1 "(d=" d ")"} 1' trace
```

**Sample Output**

```
+ 0.1 Stuff stuff and more stuff
- 0.2 Yet more stuff
r(d=0.3) 0.4 Something new
+ 0.8 Something else, not so new
- 1.6 Jiggery
r(d=2.4) 3.2 Pokery
+ 6.4 Higgledy Piggledy
```

That says... *"If you see a line starting with `+`, save the second field as variable `tx`. If you see a line starting with `r`, save the second field as variable `rx`. Calculate the difference between `rx` and `tx` and save it as `d`. Rebuild the first field of the line by appending `(d=variable d)` to the end of whatever it was. The `1` at the end tells `awk` to do its natural thing - i.e. print the line."*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort to explain in such a way.

Comment: I just tried this code and it didn't work. It's saying that the regular expression compile failed (syntax error ^* or ^+), and even if I try to fix that by putting a / in front of the +, it still says that there's a syntax error at or near a {.

Comment: @nick012000 Maybe ask a new question showing a sample of your data as things may have changed in 2 years. Questions are free. Click `share` under this answer and it will give you a link you can add to your new question to refer back to this one.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I might do that tomorrow.